# What is the equivalent security features for the obsolete com.ms.security?

Tags: java, windows, security, applet

## **Background**

I stumbled upon an old applet of mine which is extremely outdated (parts of it from 2001), and I would really like to bring it back from the dead! The applet should open a file in its native application (among other things), but this doesn't work on the latest Windows versions (including *Windows 7*), it works well on *Windows XP*.

```
        try {
                if (Class.forName("com.ms.security.PolicyEngine") != null) {
                    PolicyEngine.assertPermission(PermissionID.EXEC);
                    PolicyEngine.assertPermission(PermissionID.FILEIO);
                    PolicyEngine.assertPermission(PermissionID.NETIO);
                    PolicyEngine.assertPermission(PermissionID.UI);
                    PolicyEngine.assertPermission(PermissionID.USERFILEIO);
                    PolicyEngine.assertPermission(PermissionID.CLIENTSTORE);
                } 
                else {
                } 
         } catch (Throwable e) {
         }
```

## **Problem/Solution**

I am pretty sure that the above code has something to do with it. Is it as easy as just removing this code completely and then re-signing the applet? Or do I need to re-implement it with the *java.security* package instead before signing it? If I need to re-implement it with *java.security*, is it enough just using something similar:

```
       try {
                if (Class.forName("java.security.Policy") != null) {            
                    final Permissions permissions = new Permissions();
                    permissions.add( new java.security.AllPermission());
                    } 
                else {
                }                 
        } catch (Throwable e) {
        }
```

What do I need to make it work on **Windows 7**?

The applet is using **Java version 1.5.0 (J2SE 5.0).**

.

Cheers.

**UPDATE**

Here is the code that works in Windows XP, but does not seem to execute in Windows 7.

```
    String command = '"' + sDir + sFileName + '"';
    Runtime myRuntime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        myRuntime.exec("rundll32 SHELL32.DLL,ShellExec_RunDLL " + command);
        gGfx.setStatusText("File opened.");
        gGfx.drawStatusBar(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {

        System.out.println("Error " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: *"The applet should open a file in its native application"* If your client can run a 1.6 VM, look to `Desktop.open(File)` *"(among other things)"*  What other things?

Comment: I want to do this with version 1.5 only. "Among other things" such as create/read/edit/open/delete a file. All this works on the applet running Windows XP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it as easy as just removing this code completely and then re-signing the applet?

That is the solution here.

Comment: Ok, im trying this. Since I came up with the answer, but you helped me come up with the answer. If it works, I will accept your answer :) I think it's only fair that way.

Comment: The alternative is to add it as an answer of your own, and mark that correct.  I think it is 50/50 either way given the extensive experience, yet paucity of words, that I brought to my answer.  This comment is way longer.  ;)

Comment: Sorry, but this didn't do it. I still get the warning "Contains both signed and unsigned code" and then if I click yes. I get "trusted loader attempted to load sandboxed resource from [link]."

Comment: Interestingly enough. Now it doesn't even work in Windows XP. If I press "No" on the "Block potentially unsafe components from being run?"-warning, then nothing happens (as with Windows 7).

Comment: *"Contains both signed and unsigned code"*  That typically means that there are multiple Jars, or a mixture of Jars and loose class files.  What is the applet element used to launch it?  Edit it into the question using code formatting.

Comment: Sorry, scratch everything about "contains both signed and unsigned code" I stated earlier, I removed the jar (ms_security.jar) and that fixed it. Now it works in Windows XP, however it still doesn't work in Windows 7.

Comment: This is what I am using to open the native application, maybe it has to do something with this? myRuntime.exec("rundll32 SHELL32.DLL,ShellExec_RunDLL " + command);

Comment: `myRuntime.exec("rundll32 SHELL32.DLL,ShellExec_RunDLL " + command);` That is a classic that deserves a separate Q/A.  Be sure to state the minimum version of Java you aim to support.  1.5 (now obsolescent) brought some nice new classes for that.

Comment: BTW - the question *"What is the equivalent security features for the obsolete com.ms.security?"* is answered, isn't it?

Comment: It sure is. I'm sorry, completely forgot to accept the answer.

Comment: Cool, glad you got that sorted. :)  Let me know by comment when you ask the new question.  I'll have an answer to offer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10597/discussion-between-edz-and-andrew-thompson)